# Pushing image failed

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, ice

I tried to push some images (around 750M) and it fails after some layers push successfully Then when I restart pushing the images, I got this error message:

```
FATA[0030] Error response from daemon: v1 ping attempt failed with error: 
Get http://registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/v1/_ping: dial tcp: i/o timeout
```

Comment: Can you please add more information, like what are the images, where are you trying to push them(seems like US), which process you are following, etc...

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Do you still have this error to push images?
There was a known issue, which was solved a few days ago and now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

according to your description, it seems related to a temporary network issue on your internet connection and/or on bluemix network:
- the pushing activity could be reset to due to network problems
- the same problems prevented you to run the next command.

Anyway I see you were using beta containers registry, now containers have been released in GA so you have to change your registry url to https://registry.ng.bluemix.net